# In over my head with thin clients

Tags: remote

I have been looking into using an old (Sempron 2200+) computer for the kids to play games on. The only problem is flash games run horribly slow, one game installed with wine won't even start, and most of the kids games from the Software Center just run really choppy. I was thinking about setting the old computer up as a thin client and installing LTSP on my main Linux box. But the more I look into it the more it looks overly complicated for what I'm trying to do. I've also looked into xrdp, but I'm kind of at a loss as to how to go about doing this. Basically I just want my kids to be able to turn on their computer and have a desktop presented to them using the resources of my main box. Does anyone have any suggestions or know of any good tutorials to get me started?

Edit 2: Removed issue with Network Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this see if it helps.  Let me know and I will research it further.  On a second note, I have a Pentium 3 system for my kids, and yes its slow, but it runs everything that they need. look at maybe adding more RAM.

[Installing on top of an already running desktop system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/LTSPQuickInstall)

Comment: The part I don't understand is how to configure a spare interface for the thin client. I only have one network card and both computers are attached to a router. Can I have two network interfaces on the same computer as long as they have different IP addresses?

Comment: yes you can have 2 NICs on the same system